# How to position dynamically sized image flush with the top border?

Tags: css, image, layout, position

How can I ensure that an image is dynamically sized always has it's top edge flush with the top edge of its containing div?

As you can see in the screenshot below, the image is currently being shifted down from the top edge, which causes its position do differ from the overlaid canvas.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPn8l.jpg

**NOTE:** I have not been able to replicate the behavior in codepen, will update this whenever I get it

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yRbNWZ)

```
#image-viewer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 89px;
  left: 0;
  height: calc(100vh-89px);
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  // ...

  #main-image-slider {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    height: calc(100% - 34px);
    float: none;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    object-fit: contain;

    .slide {
      display: none;
      max-height: 100%;
      width: auto;
      // ...

      .canvas {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
      }

      .crop-image-wrapper {
        text-align: center;
        max-height: calc(100% - 108px);

        img {
          height: calc(100vh - 108px);
          max-height: 100%;
          max-width: 100%;
          object-fit: contain;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `object-fit` has it's own positioning setting with `object-position`. Adding `object-position: top` to the img element did the trick!